# destructing object's function in JavaScript ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
const circle = {
  radius: 10,
  color: 'orange',
  getArea: function() {
    return Math.PI * this.radius * this.radius;
  },
  getCircumference: function() {
    return 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;
  }
};

let {radius, getArea, getCircumference} = circle;
console.log(getArea());
```

I get the radius vale and color, but when I call getArea(1) or getArea(5) I get NaN, how do I get the function to work ?

expected to get 314.15

Comment: When you separate functions from their objects you lose the binding to `this`. Called like that `this.radius` will be undefined.

Comment: Like Mark said, `this` no longer refers to `circle`. You would have to do `getArea.apply(circle)` or use `.bind()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For normal functions, the value of `this` is determined by how you call a function. If you call:

```
circle.getArea()
```

Then that says to call the getArea function with `this` equal to `circle`. If instead you have a standalone function and call

```
getArea()
```

Then you havn't told it what `this` should equal, so it defaults to the window object (in non-strict mode) or undefined (in strict mode). Instead, either call it the first way, or use [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)/[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to explicitly set the value of this

```
getArea.call(circle)
```

Or create a bound copy of the function.

```
const boundGetArea = circle.getArea.bind(circle);
boundGetArea();
```

Comment: Introducing call and bind methods is very confusing for him at this point i guess

Comment: Call is not, but bound is kind of confusing, I'll use the first method